# ToolTip for ComboBox items in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, combobox, tooltip, silverlight-5.0

I just want to add a `ToolTip` for each item in a Silverlight Custom `ComboBox`. so when a user moves around items can see `ToolTip`, items in `ComboBox` will be of type string and the same value will be displayed as `ToolTip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tooltip by adding a simple data template -- give the template `TextBlock` with the tool tip added:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding}" Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

---

**Edit** - Using Code behind

```
var dt = new DataTemplate();
var tb = new TextBlock();
tb.ToolTip = new Binding(".");
tb.Text = new Binding(".");
dt.VisualTree = tb;

var cb = new ComboBox();
cb.ItemTemplate = dt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried above solution but it doesn't work in my application. I am generating a Custom ComboBox control. Is it possible to add ToolTip in code behind?

Comment: @NileshSarvaiya Sure, I updated my answer to show the equivalent using code-behind.

Comment: I am getting ToolTip is not found in type TextBlock error .. any help?